# React Native Linking: Skipping the call prompt

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, deep-linking

Is there any way of using the following telephone call option in React Native:

```
import {Linking} from 'react-native'
Linking.openURL(`tel:${phoneNumber}`)
```

but skipping the call dialogue that comes up? Just go straight to the call?

Comment: Nope, it will require Native code changes. I think it not even possible after that too.